# Richfaces and Weblogic 10.3

Tags: richfaces, weblogic-10.x

In my web.xml I have:

```
 <filter>
  <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>enable-cache</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>

  <init-param>
   <param-name>forceparser</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
```

When running in Tomcat 6 the application runs fine.
When running in Weblogic 10.3 I get a lot of ResourceNotFoundExceptions:

```
org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not registered : /org/richfaces/ui.pack.js.seam
        at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.getResource(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:408)
        at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.getResourceForKey(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:352)
        at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:152)
        at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:141)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:508)
```

Can this be solved?

When I comment out the filter the application seems to run fine.
I need to use Weblogic due to customer demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common issue with Richfaces and Weblogic

From http://seamframework.org/Community/RichFacesIssueResourceNotRegistered

> So, for those that also run into the
>   before mentioned
>   'ResourceNotFoundException', try the
>   following and your problem will
>   probably be solved:
>
> 1. Clear your browser''s cache (CTRL+F5 on IE)
> 2. Upgrade your Richfaces library to atleast 3.1.5 (as this version
>      solved some issues related to this
>      exception) or 3.2.0SR1
> 3. If you're using Java 6, downgrade to Java 5

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error message with Seam 2.2.2.Final, RichFaces 3.3.4.Final and WebLogic 12c. Removing the filter definition from the application's web.xml seemed to help. Seam should install the filter automatically, see for example https://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/configuration.html#d0e24558